# how to run a python code by Nsight system in Windows

Tags: windows, python

I'm new here, I would like to know how I can run a python script in Nvidia Nsight Systems in windows. All the methods I saw on the internet are basically in Ubuntu systems and by the terminal (which I'm not able to reproduce). I'm trying to run the script directly on Nsight systems, but actually I don't know how to use Nsight systems at all, sorry my ignorance.

Down bellow I'm showing a pic of my window and how I'm trying to run

[Nsight view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scvFC.png)

My python script is in the `C:\Users\Bruni\Documents\PythonScripts\` folder and its name is `EquilibriumKernelGPU(float32).py`. I don't know if this application should be an executable file `.exe`, actually I don't know how to convert my application to `.exe` (the method I saw on the internet didn't work for me, I don't know if it was because of libraries, that are basically `Numpy` and `Numba`).

I I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you installed [Numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/installing.html) and [Numpy](https://numpy.org/install/)?  Are you aware that your Nsight project has zero files, so there wouldn't anything to build (run), with your project in it's current state.

Comment: you mean installed in the computer (regular way)? or somehow linked with Nsight? but which file should be inside the project? the python script? Sorry for the questions, I really have no experience with nsight

Comment: I linked to the instructions for both Python packages.  What files are required entirely depend on what your project does. Nsight View is an analysis tool, it will analyze your project, it needs **your** files.

Comment: I see now, I have both of them installed

Comment: @Ramhound actually it is just one Python code  of a simulation done using CUDA, the script necessarily needs to be in `.exe` ? or it can be run just as `.py` ?

Comment: You have a great deal more research to do before I can answer your question